# Dimension of solution space to nonlinear system of equations

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, implicit-function

My lecture notes leading up to the implicit function theorem state the following:

> We investigate underdetermined systems of equations $f(x) = b$ where
> $f$ : $\mathbb{R}^{n+k} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is
> given. Note that it is sufficient to consider the case $b = 0$ since
> we can subtract $b$ from $f$. Thus we consider the solution space $M
> := f^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.
>
> Each component of $f$ gives rise to an equation. Writing $M = \{x :
> f_1(x) = 0\} \cap... \cap \{x : f_k(x) = 0\}$ we see that each scalar
> equation reduces the dimension of the solution space by one. Thus we
> expect $M$ to be $n$-dimensional with codimension $k$. Our task is to
> find a way to parameterize the set of solutions.

Now for a subspace of a vector space it is clear what dimension means, but the solution set as a subset of a vector space is not necessarily a vector space. So my question is how to define dimension in this case?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension) mentions that:

> In physics and mathematics, the dimension of a mathematical space (or
> object) is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates
> needed to specify any point within it. Thus a line has a
> dimension of one (1D) because only one coordinate is needed to specify
> a point on it – for example, the point at 5 on a number line. A
> surface such as a plane or the surface of a cylinder or sphere has a
> dimension of two (2D) because two coordinates are needed to specify a
> point on it – for example, both a latitude and longitude are required
> to locate a point on the surface of a sphere. The inside of a cube, a
> cylinder or a sphere is three-dimensional (3D) because three
> coordinates are needed to locate a point within these spaces.

Is there a more rigorous definition? Is this why we introduce the concept of manifolds?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you assuming the function is surjective -- else it could have a bigger kernel even in the linear case, e.g. $f(x,y,z) = (x,x)$ in which the preimages are either $2$-dimensional (translates) or empty. The second equation doesn't reduce anything since it's the same as the first.

Comment: The author does not mention any restriction although earlier in the example for the linear case full rank was assumed.